# HTML5 creating an animated 2d image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

newbie HTML5 developer here,

I was digging in on the web to create a animated image using several jpg files that I should have in some folder in my website. 
The idea is to create a animation of a rabbit running from one side of the page to another when the user clicks on a button.

So, what I've found so far are libraries that transform images, and allow me to move them, but what I really need is to get the images changing while -let's say I have a div in which the rabbit images are placed- the rabbit is moving.

imgs/
    rabbit-image1.jpg
    rabbit-image2.jpg
    rabbit-image3.jpg
    rabbit-image4.jpg
    rabbit-image5.jpg
    rabbit-image6.jpg

Once I start to move the  from one point of the page to another, I would like these the images to loop until the  reaches the ending position, giving a feeling of a running rabbit.

Any suggestions? Thank you in advance.

Comment: What suggestions do you want? Go do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Animating images is pretty simple.
All you need to do is to provide the images and their order (array)
aswell as some kind of timer

```
function Animation(images, timePerImage) {
    this.images = images;                     // array of rabbit images
    this.currentTime = 0;                     // timer
    this.currentImage = 0;                    // current rabbit image
    this.imageCount = images.length;          // amount of images
    this.timePerImage = timePerImage || 100;  // displaytime per image
};

Animation.prototype.constructor = Animation;

// ticker, every frame we add the elapsed time to the current time
// if the current time is bigger than the time per image, then we pick the next index
Animation.prototype.tick = function(elapsed) {
    this.currentTime += elapsed;
    if(this.currentTime >= this.timePerImage) {
        this.currentImage++;
        if(this.currentImage >= this.imageCount) {
            this.currentImage = 0;
        }
        this.currentTime = 0;
    }
};

// gets the image on the current image index
Animation.prototype.getImage = function() {
    return this.images[this.currentImage];
};

// load tha rabbit images
var rabbits = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    rabbits[i] = new Image();
    rabbits[i].src = "imgs/rabbit-image" + (i+1) + ".jpg";
    // if you are not using canvas, then you could just do:
    // rabbits[i] = "imgs/rabbit-image" + (i+1) + ".jpg";
}

// create the animation
var rabbit = new Animation(rabbits);

// loop
var time = Date.now();
function loop() {
    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
    var elapsed = Date.now() - time;
    time += elapsed;

    // clear your canvas
    // move the rabbit position

    rabbit.tick(elapsed); // call this if the rabbit is still moving
    var image = rabbit.getImage(); // get the current image
    // now draw the image to the rabbit position
}
```

On a sidenote: There are several frameworks for canvas rendering. You might want to take a look into pixi.js which already handles things like animations for you.

If you are not using canvas, then instead of using an array of rabbit images, you can just use an array of strings.